# How to use Select in Joins in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have created a temp table with pivot as below:

```
INSERT into A_temp_table(PER_KEY, LANDLINE, FAX, MOBILE)
    select * from
    (select PER_KEY, TEL_NUM, from ABC.V_PER_TEL) 
    pivot(max(TEL_NUM) for TEL_TYPE_DESC in ('LANDLINE', 'FAX', 'MOBILE'));
```

After this I am fetching the data using joins as below:

```
SELECT P.PERSON_KEY,
      P.FIRST_NAME,
      P.MIDDLE_NAME,
      P.LAST_NAME,
      PT.LANDLINE,
      PT.FAX,
      PT.MOBILE,

FROM ABC.V_PER P

    LEFT OUTER JOIN A_temp_table PT ON P.PER_KEY=PT.PER_KEY
```

My Question is:

Can I replace the temp table used in join with the select statement directly.
Like below:

```
SELECT P.PERSON_KEY,
      P.FIRST_NAME,
      P.MIDDLE_NAME,
      P.LAST_NAME,
      PT.LANDLINE,
      PT.FAX,
      PT.MOBILE,

FROM ABC.V_PER P

    LEFT OUTER JOIN (select * from
    (select PER_KEY, TEL_NUM, from ABC.V_PER_TEL) 
    pivot(max(TEL_NUM) for TEL_TYPE_DESC in ('LANDLINE', 'FAX', 'MOBILE'))) PT  ON P.PER_KEY=PT.PER_KEY
```

But, in doing the above step My code is not running.

Is there any other way to remove temp table use, and why my way is not working.

Please help,

Comment: What do you mean with "not running"? Are you having an error? If so, please post it. Also is this the whole query or a part? Are you sure you posted the exact SQL you used? for example, even the first INSERT statement has error

Comment: I am getting the error invalid identifier PT.Landline,PT.Fax,PT.Mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you need to use alias for the columns from the PIVOT; for example:

```
create table testPivot(v varchar2(10), n number);
insert into testPivot values ('A', 10);
insert into testPivot values ('A', 10);
insert into testPivot values ('B', 10);
```

This will give error:

```
SQL> select A
  2  from (
  3        select *
  4        from testPivot
  5        pivot(max(n) for v in ('A', 'B'))
  6        );
select A
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "A": invalid identifier
```

This will work:

```
SQL> select A
  2  from (
  3        select *
  4        from testPivot
  5        pivot(max(n) for v in ('A' as A, 'B' as B))
  6        );

         A
----------
        10
```